Issue with dynamic schema validation in React Hook Form using Yup
I'm using React Hook Form with Yup for schema validation and need to adjust the schema dynamically based on a field's value.
  const getDynamicSchema = (scenario = '') => {
    switch (scenario) {
      case "Create":
        return actionSchema
      case "edit":
        return actionSchema
      default:
        return yup.object();
    }
  };
const defaultValues = { scenario: 'Create' }

  const methods = useForm<DefaultValue>({ defaultValues: defaultValues, mode: "onChange", resolver: yupResolver(getDynamicSchema(watch("scenario"))), })
  const { watch, getValues, setValue, reset } = methods

I'm facing an issue where the schema does not update when the value of scenario changes. The form validation seems to remain based on the initial schema.
And also i couldnt get the value scenario fields from react-hooks-form.
 useEffect(() => {
   
    reset(defaultValues, {
      resolver: yupResolver(getValidationSchema(scenario)), 
    });
  }, [scenario, reset, defaultValues]);

But here resolve is not available in reset method.
